# Adding a location that is tied to a userID via Foreign Key

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm learning .NET here and have build a small API that allows me to register users, retrieve user lists, or a single user, as well as edit them.  Microsoft Identity is used for most of this process.

I am now trying to add new section to this API that will handle physical locations.  Each location will be tied back to a specific user, so there may be one or multiple locations per user.  I'm having trouble building this part of it though.  I cant seem to figure out how to tie the ID of the user to the location as a foreign key.  I've been battling this one now for quite some time.

I have the controller build for the location calls, and the DTO's, but it does not seem to want to actually work correctly.

Anyone up to talking a look and letting me know what needs to be done and how to do this? I'm a bit lost and really wanting to learn how this works. The github repo with the full working project is here:

https://github.com/sapper6fd/API

Comment: Regarding the part "but it does not seem to want to actually work correctly". Can you elaborate on what you had done and what failed?

Comment: I just cloned your repository and tested it. it adds locations fine and it is tied to the users. I guess you are just missing an Include? check this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue at hand here was the way it was configured.

The following adjustments fixed the issue:

CreateLocation() method:

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreateLocation(int clientId, LocationCreateDto locationCreateDto)
        {
            //  Grab the current users roles to verify they have access to this API call
            var userRole = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Role).ToString();

            if (userRole != "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role: GlobalAdmin")
                return Unauthorized();

            // Create the new location
            var newLocation = _mapper.Map<Locations>(locationCreateDto);

            _repo.Add(newLocation);

            if (await _repo.SaveAll())
            {
                var locationToReturn = _mapper.Map<LocationCreateDto>(newLocation);
                return CreatedAtRoute(nameof(GetLocation), new { id = locationToReturn.Id, userid=clientId }, locationToReturn);
            }
            throw new Exception("Unable to create new location. Failed to save.");
        }
```

HttpGet Method:

```
[HttpGet("{id}", Name = nameof(GetLocation))]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetLocation(int id)
        {
            var location = await _repo.GetLocation(id);

            var locationToReturn = _mapper.Map<LocationCreateDto>(location);

            return Ok(locationToReturn);
        }
```